# How does hivemq limit the amout of a user's subscriptions?

Tags: mqtt, hivemq

I have read hivemq plugin development document, and could'nt find any solution.

I want to limit a user's subscription count. Any help?

Comment: How useful is limiting subscription count when wild cards can be used to match all topics?

Comment: I think hivemq will load all subscription of a client from disk(file persistence) when the client connected,  so I think if it has too many subscriptions will need more time to handle it. Isn't it?

Comment: Is it a problem? Anyway, you should develop you own plugin to count subscriptions and eventually don't allow them.

Comment: But if I deny subscription, It will kick user, not send puback with grant code 0x80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question moved to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hivemq/R8FHHXfuawE

The author of hivemq answered me.